# Ruby OCI8 DBI, how to check query generated after parameter binding? need to check for "in" queries

Tags: ruby, dbi, oci8

While using Ruby-DBI I am facing issues with parameter binding for where "in" queries.
Two questions:

1. How do I get sql generated after parameter binding?
2. Does `in` parameter for sql work properly if using DBI and OCI8?

My code looks like this:

```
dbh = DBI.connect(setting[:tns], setting[:username], setting[:password])
#date and in_params are parameters to sql query.
#In the query they are seen as ? "Question marks"
sth = dbh.execute(File.read('import_values.sql'), date, in_params)
```

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT date, col1, col2
FROM TABLEX
WHERE date = ?
  AND col1 not in ( ? )
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-factored code to not use "in".